# Add additional overloads interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have interfaces for UI.

```
interface IFrame {
    onEvent(event: 'onHide', handler:(frame: IFrame) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onShow', handler:(frame: IFrame) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onChangeSize', handler:(frame: IFrame, w: number, h: number) => void): void;

    show(): void;
    hide(): void;
    getName(): string;
    setSize(w: number, h: number): void;
}
```

```
interface IButton extends IFrame {
    onEvent(event: 'onClick', handler:(frame: IButton) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onDisable', handler:(frame: IButton) => void): void;

    setDisable(): void;
    click(): void;
}
```

```
interface IEditBox extends IFrame {
    onEvent(event: 'onTextChanged', handler:(frame: IEditBox, newText: string) => void): void;

    setText(text: string): void;
    getText(): string;
}
```

I need IButton and IEditBox to have 'onEvent' overloads from IFrame too.
So that the following code can work correctly

```
class TestClass {
    constructor(but: IButton) {
        but.onEvent('onChangeSize', (self, w, h) => {
            console.log(`onChangeSize ${w}, ${h}`);
        });
        but.onEvent('onClick', (self) => {
            console.log(`button ${self.getName()} click`);
        });
    }
}
```

I tried to separate the event interfaces, but it still didn't help.

```
interface IFrame extends IFrameEvent {
    ...
}

interface IButton extends IFrame, IButtonEvent {
    ...
}

interface IEditBox extends IFrame, IEditBoxEvent {
    ...
}

interface IFrameEvent {
    onEvent(event: 'onHide', handler:(frame: IFrame) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onShow', handler:(frame: IFrame) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onChangeSize', handler:(frame: IFrame, w: number, h: number) => void): void;
}

interface IButtonEvent extends IFrameEvent {
    onEvent(event: 'onClick', handler:(frame: IButton) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onDisable', handler:(frame: IButton) => void): void;
}

interface IEditBoxEvent extends IFrameEvent {
    onEvent(event: 'onTextChanged', handler:(frame: IEditBox, newText: string) => void): void;
}
```

This option helps, but it looks ugly. Inheritance looks terrible now

```
interface IFrame extends IFrameEvent {
    show(): void;
    hide(): void;
    getName(): string;
    setSize(w: number, h: number): void;
}

type TFrameContentAndButEvent = IFrame & IButtonEvent;
interface IButton extends TFrameContentAndButEvent {
    setDisable(): void;
    click(): void;
}

type TFrameContentAndEditEvent = IFrame & IEditBoxEvent;
interface IEditBox extends TFrameContentAndEditEvent {
    setText(text: string): void;
    getText(): string;
}

interface IFrameEvent {
    onEvent(event: 'onHide', handler:(frame: IFrame) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onShow', handler:(frame: IFrame) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onChangeSize', handler:(frame: IFrame, w: number, h: number) => void): void;
}

interface IButtonEvent {
    onEvent(event: 'onClick', handler:(frame: IButton) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onDisable', handler:(frame: IButton) => void): void;
}

interface IEditBoxEvent {
    onEvent(event: 'onTextChanged', handler:(frame: IEditBox, newText: string) => void): void;
}
```

And if it is required that, for example, in the handler from onHide there was not an IFrame, but the interface that called it. We'll have to resort to generics, and that looks even worse

```
interface IFrame extends IFrameEvent<IFrame> {
    ...
}

type TFrameContentAndButEvent = IFrame & IButtonEvent<IButton>;
interface IButton extends TFrameContentAndButEvent {
    ...
}

type TFrameContentAndEditEvent = IFrame & IEditBoxEvent<IEditBox>;
interface IEditBox extends TFrameContentAndEditEvent {
    ...
}

interface IFrameEvent<T extends IFrame> {
    onEvent(event: 'onHide', handler:(frame: T) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onShow', handler:(frame: T) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onChangeSize', handler:(frame: T, w: number, h: number) => void): void;
}

interface IButtonEvent<T extends IButton> {
    onEvent(event: 'onClick', handler:(frame: T) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onDisable', handler:(frame: T) => void): void;
}

interface IEditBoxEvent<T extends IEditBox> {
    onEvent(event: 'onTextChanged', handler:(frame: T, newText: string) => void): void;
}
```

And even in this case, the handler onShow parameter will be an IFrame, not an IButton for example.

I'm sure there are better ways to solve this problem.

P.S. I must say right away that typescript here is just a declaration for Lua. I can't create a class, I need the final interface to have total overloads from all parents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using an Abstract class as an interface

You could model this as an abstract class. A class when used as a type is basically just an interface with a constructor that exists at runtime. An abstract class removes that constructor. So you can use an abstract class as a type just like you'd use an interface as a type.

But this gives you the benefit of `this` as a type, which represents the type of an instance of that class.

So imagine a class like this:

```
abstract class MyLuaBase<Events extends Record<string, unknown[]>> {
  abstract onEvent<T extends keyof Events>(
    event: T,
    handler: (...args: [frame: this, ...customArgs: Events[T]]) => void,
  ): void
}
```

Notice how the first argument of handler is always `this`, which will be whatever type is extending `MyLuaBase`.

Now you could do:

```
interface FancyFrame extends MyLuaBase<{ onFancy: [isFancy: boolean] }> {
    makeFancy(): void
}
declare const fancyFrame: FancyFrame
fancyFrame.onEvent('onFancy', (frame, isFancy) => frame.makeFancy()) // fine
```

But it sounds like you *really* frame an `IFrame` to be your base interface, so make a generic one that forwards the `Events` mapping as before.

```
interface IFrame<Events extends Record<string, unknown[]> = {}> extends MyLuaBase<
  Events & {
    onHide: []
    onShow: []
    onChangeSize: [w: number, h: number]
  }
> {
  show(): void
  hide(): void
  getName(): string
  setSize(w: number, h: number): void
}

declare const frame: IFrame
frame.onEvent('onChangeSize', (frame, w, h) => {}) // fine
```

And now you can easily extend that like so:

```
interface IButton extends IFrame<{
  onClick: []
  onDisable: []
}> {
  setDisable(): void
  click(): void
}


declare const button: IButton
button.onEvent('onShow', (frame) => frame.setDisable()) // call button method in callback from base
button.onEvent('onClick', (frame) => {}) // fine
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgTwDIFdgAhNAUwB4BRAN1IDsINSAPCegEwwCVTYB7KO3KQoASzoBzADQJ8dANZ0+AdzoBtALoA+LQgDeAKAQJQIuIj50a9COQAqCFmzqcE80tj4AzBNYZgtAAojY0daBgAuBDspEOMAC2AXZFIoKMCAOizgKAkwKLUvGABbUiiIeNEwGSyM2HxIPmKAQVz833DGNTsNDQBKBABeXWo+UXZY4z6o0fGDAF8DA3E2KC84UgQAMSTYbC2SzacODBwCYjJyPQRLHbo9gqq7h4QQPj4UpI0Eed1DUIQxWA7me2EC0wQs3YCwM7F4qCgm34dEgCHW932hyioIOwFKBnRe1xpQylj8EECAHJbrtsJSZIEinjSDInrSBsM0YcMkCQbTwQMAPSCtHiUhLZYMVLrWCbACSxIo5KYrBOCB4-EEwmg4mksgUSlUml0g30v0cqpcpzwhBIYAoIWVCAAZPo4jc6AAJcZlBCad2WADK8RUBQ0AboAGFEpJSIHRAAvX1qZRROj4YogVIyeJpjNZqDh4yLP4hMAh5TgmZjaEJH1VyE1kISUgQAByzIbIl1Zdb8aTgVTCHTmezCFzw-zqQhUJhsPhOSRllRTNKUQVhwJ3LJnSplmjSRb-dI9IQjMOMmUOY5f3mQpFXjFSxW0o2CDlRHwEAglhCxyt76KlcEaRsgoiwPIYYRgAIlUoApFBxalsY9oQLBYDwaQDazsYKDgfI2FNos84oIuSDLogIBfj+dDrp+36-lRDF0KSVi7tSdDBiop7nsyN5csyGSoehmECggwpIMAyDIK81GWICrYhuwCDiJJ0kgHA8hck0rxkAYTE0ax5J7lGYEQTxq6kPxeh3uJD5PkAA)

---

### Original answer:

I don't think adding overloads to an interface by extension is going to work. I propose a new strategy with some generic types.

First, lets pull out just the interface that provides the type for `onEvent`.

```
interface HandlesEvents<
    Events extends Record<string, unknown[]>
> {
    onEvent<T extends keyof Events>(
        event: T,
        handler: (...args: Events[T]) => void
    ): void
}


// Testing...
type Test = HandlesEvents<{ onFoo: [a: number, b: string ]}>
// { onEvent(event: 'onFoo', handler: (a: number, b: string) => void) }
```

This provides a way to construct the `onEvent` method's parameters all at once instead of relying on combining overloads. We can pass in a mapping of event types and their arguments.

---

Now to use that we can change `IFrame` to this:

```
interface IFrame<
    Events extends Record<string, unknown[]> = Record<string, never>
> extends HandlesEvents<Events & {
    onHide: [frame: IFrame<Events>]
    onShow: [frame: IFrame<Events>]
    onChangeSize: [frame: IFrame<Events>, w: number, h: number]
}> {
    show(): void;
    hide(): void;
    getName(): string;
    setSize(w: number, h: number): void;
}


// Testing...

declare const frame: IFrame
frame.onEvent('onHide', (frame) => {}) // fine

declare const fancyFrame: IFrame<{ onFancy: [isFancy: boolean] }>
fancyFrame.onEvent('onFancy', (isFancy) => {}) // fine
```

Now `IFrame` is a generic interface. Let's walk through that.

This:

```
Events extends Record<string, unknown[]> = {}
```

Means that it takes a generic type `Events` which must be `Record<string, unknown[]>`, which is the same type as what `HandlesEvents` takes.

But if omitted, then `Events` has a default type of `{}`, an empty object.

Then this:

```
extends HandlesEvents<Events & {
    onHide: [frame: IFrame<Events>]
    onShow: [frame: IFrame<Events>]
    onChangeSize: [frame: IFrame<Events>, w: number, h: number]
}>
```

Provides the base events that `IFrame` supports, intersected with any additional event types that you may want to add to this list. This is what allows you to extend the `onEvent` types from other interfaces.

---

Now extending this interface looks like this:

```
interface IButton extends IFrame<{
    onClick: [frame: IButton]
    onDisable: [frame: IButton]
}> {
    setDisable(): void;
    click(): void;
}

declare const button: IButton
button.onEvent('onShow', (frame) => {}) // fine
button.onEvent('onClick', (frame) => {}) // fine
```

Here `IButton` extends `IFrame<AdditionalEventsHere>`, and then declares its unique properties from there.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBJxAEwDYQM4CiAbhOHgDwBQyNyxpYeyEAHpFkwEoQID2UmcnjBRQAcwA0yAK4gA1iF4B3EAG0AugD5Km5AG9qtXiHrhyAFWZtSmJnIgBPXjDokymgBSHatCG7AAXMjmEt4+yAAWGDjQQR4AdIlwUGJ4QaaMqubqAJTIALy6RLzAmGE5QcWllAC+lJRgDgAOKOb4YAVo0biE-hR6yMYAYry8QapwQSDSALYARtBSc0HCoiBiyOo12gD0O-qDJv4efgxBAOTDo+dSUVi4UHGTyNPzi8jLyKvieYXIVZg8nV6vVQJBYIgUABJIZQOAzCBUHwZJisdi2ZDcPgCIQicRSWQKZRqLSdPR1XRomxMdD3fAo8go5AAMn0YWMqFKEHGMDhCKCML5iJRmnU7JAAGUIsoeUKBbD4cK+qLxQBhO5iCAS4AAL25yFUvMV8qFjOVUiUU1mCygtytbygYu2bJ8eGlSg8FX+JUwAG4whEuZ7Kj7-T5NWAAHKK4NfPHrMO0PAQMDavUeS0va3vCL2m1egH+4GYHjYZIoPggYTII385CCxWUWsQeLGDIeS4gTklm7IDzN366cl5PY10AQeolhBlqAV4zV+AgBAOBV1hsI8gDYYYZfjYB4IY7hxBOajXAYdTIbZNo+rltt46dw9Lhy9jz75-Lwf6Goj-YwccQUoMFoHgJB6wAIWkMAwGMKx0SYddEQMHxjFVbBgAQORZWNSDoNgkAxVQkAABF9zgOZcBwtcoJg4wnSHMJkzAMi8Ao3BY0LMJp0wuRONDWpJ1LctkEras5nw4wBVogjKAkuiQFbI4GA7YwpWUN8BwKIdf2QUcAJACd5IIpT207dDeM0oVv2HPT-3HIA)

Comment: Wonderful! The structure is indeed much cleaner. But there is one problem, with this approach, the frame in the handler always returns the parent class, with child events, but no methods.
`button.onEvent('onShow', (frame) => frame.click())` // not fine

Comment: Hmm, I see! Well I think if you start with an `abstract class` you can use the `this` type, which should provide what you want. See my update.

Comment: Yes thanks, it works!
But `Record<string, unknown[]>` confuses me a little. Because of it, code autocompletion does not work correctly.
If you change it to `Record<string, () => void>;` autocomplete works fine, but how do you push this to the beginning?

Comment: Code completion works for me https://imgur.com/a/6v1LHzy

Comment: What do you think of the answer below? Is it normal or are there some pitfalls?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by type intersection and `this` in function variable declaration.

```
type Intersection<T1, T2> = T1 & T2

interface IFrame extends IFrameEvent {
    //...
}

interface IButton extends Intersection<IFrame, IButtonEvent> {
    //...
}

interface IEditBox extends Intersection<IFrame, IEditBoxEvent> {
    //...
}

interface IFrameEvent {
    onEvent(event: 'onHide', handler:(frame: this) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onShow', handler:(frame: this) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onChangeSize', handler:(frame: this, w: number, h: number) => void): void;
}

interface IButtonEvent {
    onEvent(event: 'onClick', handler:(frame: this) => void): void;
    onEvent(event: 'onDisable', handler:(frame: this) => void): void;
}

interface IEditBoxEvent {
    onEvent(event: 'onTextChanged', handler:(frame: this, newText: string) => void): void;
}
```